# Command to restart Squid proxy server?

Tags: linux, command-line, squid

What command restarts the Squid proxy server on Linux distros?

I have tried <strike>`squid restart`</strike>, is that the correct command?

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: I am sorry I am a novice user. What od you mean by distribution?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution

Answer (score 22):

Most of the time services are started via the init system you can probably restart your service with

```
/etc/init.d/squid restart
```

or on debian / ubuntu you should use the service application

```
service squid restart
```

or

```
service squid3 restart
```

But maybe we should relay on tab completion to auto complete to the proper service:

```
service squid<TAB> restart
```

Comment: on Ubuntu 14 it is `service squid3 restart`

Comment: on CentOS 6 it is `service squid restart`